# MacPorts 1.8.2 fails to build db46 on Mac OS X 1.6.3

Tags: java, macos, macports

I'm trying to put a development environment on my Mac, and to do so I need to install several packages which require db46.

When running

```
sudo port install db46
```

I get the following error:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for db46
--->  Fetching db46
--->  Attempting to fetch patch.4.6.21.1 from http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/update/4.6.21/
--->  Attempting to fetch patch.4.6.21.2 from http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/update/4.6.21/
--->  Attempting to fetch patch.4.6.21.3 from http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/update/4.6.21/
--->  Attempting to fetch patch.4.6.21.4 from http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/update/4.6.21/
--->  Attempting to fetch db-4.6.21.tar.gz from http://distfiles.macports.org/db4/4.6.21_6
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for db46
--->  Extracting db46
--->  Applying patches to db46
--->  Configuring db46
--->  Building db46
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix" && /usr/bin/make -j2 all " returned error 2
Command output: ../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9464: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9487: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jlong'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9509: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9532: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jlong'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9563: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jint'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9588: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jlong'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9613: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jint'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9638: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9666: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jlong'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9691: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jlong'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9716: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9739: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9771: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9796: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9819: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9842: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9867: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jobject'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9899: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9920: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9943: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9966: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jstring'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:9991: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'jint'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:10010: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:10046: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../dist/../libdb_java/db_java_wrap.c:10071: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
make: *** [db_java_wrap.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
cd ./classes && jar cf ../db.jar ./com/sleepycat

Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

I have removed my `/usr/local` folder completely and it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're missing the JDK tools
https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20719

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 1.6.3? I hope you mean 10.6.3. Anyway, [the MacPorts bug reporting system](https://trac.macports.org/) is the place to report these things, not  StackOverflow.  You will need to talk with them there to get this worked out.